# What does "I will not touch any firearm during a cattle fire." mean?

Tags: phrases, american-english, sentence

> I will not touch any firearm during a cattle fire.

It's said in a gun shooting range in Texas, at the counter inside, before they are given weapons. They are made to say it out loud and sign a paper. "Cattle fire" could be something else; I just think it sounds like "cattle fire". If it's actually something else, I still wonder what the meaning of this is.

The video clip (less than 27 seconds long): https://streamable.com/e/ud24gn

Comment: Why don't you tell the _original_ source of this?

Comment: or *ceasefire*, which makes sense.

Comment: Both speakers are clearly not native English speakers, so we cannot tell what word it is that they are mispronouncing.

Comment: @PhilSweet WOW!  If that is what they are trying to pronounce, and it comes out like that, how the hell are they gonna recognize the the correct pronunciation at the critical moment?

Comment: The video seems faked.

Comment: @HotLicks It's a real range. [Lone Star Gun Range](https://www.lonestargunrange.com/)

Comment: It's possible that it's supposed to be "ceasefire".  Or some similar term that's used on a gun range.

Comment: '_Cease_ fire'? Whoops, I thought you said "Fire!"

Comment: I suppose it might be "cancel fire".